# Visual Studio - Set project output path versus using xcopy in post build event

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I think its a rather simple question but I couldn't really find an answer for it so I will ask it in case someone else might need it .

There are developers who in-order to copy all projects to bin folder set the bin folder path using the project output path property and there are developers who use the xcopy command in post build event.

What are the main reasons for it ?

Regards ,

James Roeiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting project output path is a better option. The reason is that in this case Visual Studio is in control: it takes care of cleaning up, replacing older files, deciding which files to copy... When using xcopy, Visual Studio just invokes blindly a batch file. It will run all the commands on the batch which will result in files being copied whether they were compiled or not. Also, if the compilation order of projects changes, or new projects are added or removed, the corresponding post-build actions need to be updated, resulting in extra steps.